# How to Solve This STM32F303 I2C initialization Problem

Tags: stm32, i2c

I am trying to move a project to the STM32F103 from STM32F303, so I should recode some things.

```
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
```

This part of the code was working fine but now I get error messages because STM32f3 HAL library has initializations only for Timing registers.

How can I arrange clock speed and duty-cycle in this case? Can you explain it using these pieces of code?

Comment: You need to provide more information - such as the exact error messages you are getting.
It looks like you are using the HAL driver for the I2C - in which case the code may have been generated using CubeMX.
It is best - if possible - to create a new CubeMX project for the STM32F303 - and reconfigure the I2C peripheral there.